# Is this stationary? If it's not, how to adjust to stationary?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

[image]

```
Lag:
  [1,]  1.0000000
  [2,]  0.7016108
  [3,]  0.1822176
  [4,] -0.2005085
  [5,] -0.3720271
  [6,] -0.4296546
  [7,] -0.4425781
  [8,] -0.4276270
  [9,] -0.3677677
 [10,] -0.2005806
 [11,]  0.1660284
 [12,]  0.6538072
 [13,]  0.8976778
 [14,]  0.6550189
 [15,]  0.1619369
 [16,] -0.2081749
 [17,] -0.3703354
 [18,] -0.4263054
 [19,] -0.4400371
 [20,] -0.4274330
 [21,] -0.3706300
 [22,] -0.2045828
 [23,]  0.1634924
 [24,]  0.6511853
 [25,]  0.8934141
 [26,]  0.6517700
 [27,]  0.1602911
 [28,] -0.2090080
 [29,] -0.3694286
 [30,] -0.4229242
 [31,] -0.4353206
 [32,] -0.4213788
 [33,] -0.3651737
 [34,] -0.2032641
 [35,]  0.1568259
 [36,]  0.6270976
 [37,]  0.8608968
 [38,]  0.6336082
 [39,]  0.1586365
 [40,] -0.2046252
 [41,] -0.3644586
 [42,] -0.4163194
 [43,] -0.4274588
 [44,] -0.4138391
 [45,] -0.3582659
 [46,] -0.2015262
 [47,]  0.1473478
 [48,]  0.6129927
 [49,]  0.8477564
 [50,]  0.6046533
 [51,]  0.1409829
 [52,] -0.2060424
 [53,] -0.3600804
 [54,] -0.4111623
 [55,] -0.4219467
 [56,] -0.4077631
 [57,] -0.3531171
 [58,] -0.1983487
 [59,]  0.1424590
 [60,]  0.5974680
 [61,]  0.8298390
 [62,]  0.6074773
 [63,]  0.1511187
 [64,] -0.1957672
 [65,] -0.3503146
 [66,] -0.4006782
 [67,] -0.4121490
 [68,] -0.3994631
 [69,] -0.3463246
 [70,] -0.1952612
 [71,]  0.1414393
 [72,]  0.5970856
 [73,]  0.8255799
 [74,]  0.6031327
 [75,]  0.1484195
 [76,] -0.1950472
 [77,] -0.3453280
 [78,] -0.3943562
 [79,] -0.4052055
 [80,] -0.3923379
 [81,] -0.3395406
 [82,] -0.1882868
 [83,]  0.1416538
 [84,]  0.5811438
 [85,]  0.8110128
 [86,]  0.6014232
 [87,]  0.1553567
 [88,] -0.1874081
 [89,] -0.3397973
 [90,] -0.3893644
 [91,] -0.4000876
 [92,] -0.3879205
 [93,] -0.3368549
 [94,] -0.1888075
 [95,]  0.1390481
 [96,]  0.5734451
 [97,]  0.7915700
 [98,]  0.5802920
 [99,]  0.1451082
[100,] -0.1859601
[101,] -0.3348399
[102,] -0.3829952
[103,] -0.3939522
[104,] -0.3821791
[105,] -0.3325910
[106,] -0.1907379
[107,]  0.1195243
[108,]  0.5459720
[109,]  0.7741321
[110,]  0.5716930
[111,]  0.1453261
[112,] -0.1808336
[113,] -0.3271031
[114,] -0.3760791
[115,] -0.3868358
[116,] -0.3751612
[117,] -0.3262827
[118,] -0.1872577
[119,]  0.1248619
[120,]  0.5447506
[121,]  0.7608946
```

Comment: Of course this data is not stationary, what is the periodicity of data?

Comment: Year/Month/Data
1934 1 2778
1934 2 2458
1934 3 2228
1934 4 2138
1934 5 1987
1934 6 3613
1934 7 19775
1934 8 36277
1934 9 40084
1934 10 18625
1934 11 6197
1934 12 3432
1935 1 2389
1935 2 2056
1935 3 1625
1935 4 1888
1935 5 1654
1935 6 2918
1935 7 13086
1935 8 38239
1935 9 27645
1935 10 13908
1935 11 4531
1935 12 3356
 .                                                                                                                                      
 . 
 1993       12    2679

Comment: If that is the case, since the data is seasonally non stationary you want to do seasonal differencing.

Comment: If this is non stationary, how can I make it stationary?

Comment: Read my previous comment, if you want to make it stationary you want to do seasonal differencing.